# Create table which is result of the query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, create-table

There are 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICES
(
    ID INT auto_increment,
    `DATE` DATE,
    Company INT,
    Amount DECIMAL(7,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO INVOICES(`DATE`,Company,Amount)
VALUES
('2014-01-02', 222, 19500.00),
('2014-01-02', 222, 29205),
('2014-01-07', 222, 152.50),
('2014-01-07', 223, 6590),
('2014-01-07', 223, 4999),
('2014-01-09', 224, 720.60),
('2014-01-09', 225, 1100),
('2014-02-05', 226, 885),
('2014-02-05', 222, 9678.7);

create table Companies 
(
    ID  int,
    Name    varchar(100),
    City    varchar(100),
    c_size varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

insert into Companies(ID, Name, city, c_size) 
values
(222, 'Karma LLC','CITY2', 'big'),
(223, 'Manny Ind.','CITY1', 'medium'),
(224, 'Random PLC','CITY1', 'medium'),
(225, 'Hijack LLC','CITY1', 'medium'),
(226, 'Travels LLC','CITY1', 'small'),
(227, 'Mirana Ind.','CITY2', 'small'),
(228, 'Polla Ind.','CITY3', 'small'),
(229, 'Americano LLC','CITY3', 'small'),
(230, 'Macaroni LLC','CITY4', 'small');
```

My goal is to write query which say how many companies paid sum(amount) in JANUARY of invoices > 10000.
I know there are 2 companies with sum invoices for more than 10k, but idk how to make query for it, so I decided to write query:

```
select sum(brutto) as sum_january,Name,`DATE` from INVOICES,COMPANIES where INVOICES.Company=Companies.ID and MONTH(`DATE`)=01 group by Company;
```

It makes nice table with sum(Amount) for january for each companies, so I though it would be easy to make query about this table like this:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM new_table where sum_january > 10000;
```

But when I'm trying make:

```
CREATE new_table as select sum(brutto) as sum_january,Name,`DATE` from INVOICES,COMPANIES where INVOICES.Company=Companies.ID and MONTH(`DATE`)=01 group by Company;
```

There is an error: 
"ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'new_table as select sum(Amount) as sum_january,Name,`DATE` from INVOICES,Compani' at line 1"

I don't know what to do.
Is there any other idea to get all companies with invoice for january > 10000? Why mine way dosen't work?

EDIT: There was not "TABLE" word after "CREATE" in the last query... I'm done.

Comment: you dont have a TABLE written infront of the CREATE statement in your last query. is it intentional or a typo here.

Comment: OMG, you are GOD and I'm king of fools, I've spent 3h for this. Thank you so much.

Comment: I am no GOD just a ordinary person who is trying to learn and if possible help someone. but good to see your problem is resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a `select` statement to get all companies with invoices that amount in more than 10000 in the month of january:

```
select 
  COMPANIES.Name,
  sum(INVOICES.Amount) as sum_january
from 
  INVOICES
inner join
  COMPANIES on INVOICES.Company=COMPANIES.ID and 
  MONTH(INVOICES.DATE)=1 
GROUP BY 
  COMPANIES.Name
HAVING
  sum(INVOICES.Amount) > 10000
```

if you want to save that to another table write:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table as (select...)
```

or

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table AS (selec...)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, it's nice code, it helped me much to understand "HAVING" command :) It has two syntax bugs too, which I found when trying to execute:  
1) colon "," after sum_january should be removed;  2) "group by Companies.Name" should be moved before "HAVING...", otherwise it causes a syntax error.  
Thank you for your time and help! :)

Comment: @DontHurtMe thanks you are right, I'll try to be more careful next time